# Correlation Matrix in R with Fish Abundances

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a dataset comprised of fish abundances sampled on a weekly scale. I'm looking to create a matrix that shows the correlation between the abundance of 1 species to another over a particular time period. What would be the best way to do this? Can I use a pearson correlation for data of this nature?

My data includes 12 species and 20 weeks. For each week, there is a recorded abundance.

For example:

```
Week     species 1      species 2     species 3
1              150          1000            0
2              250          1500            0
3              700          1400            0
4              80           2000         1800
5              0            500         600
```

Looking for correlation between the occurrence or abundance or one species and another(s).

Comment: If you can put a sample of your data here, forum can be more helpful.

Comment: I tried to add an example of what my data would look like with the headers being week, species 1, species 2, species 3 and the values are numeric.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following basic analysis may be helpful:

```
ddf = structure(list(Week = 1:5, species1 = c(150L, 250L, 700L, 80L, 
0L), species2 = c(1000L, 1500L, 1400L, 2000L, 500L), species3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1800L, 600L)), .Names = c("Week", "species1", "species2", 
"species3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> ddf
  Week species1 species2 species3
1    1      150     1000        0
2    2      250     1500        0
3    3      700     1400        0
4    4       80     2000     1800
5    5        0      500      600
```

Correlation matrix between different species arranged along time (shows some direct correlation between species2 and 3, and inverse correlation between species1 and 3):

```
cor(ddf[,2:4])
           species1  species2   species3
species1  1.0000000 0.2494514 -0.4905172
species2  0.2494514 1.0000000  0.4699644
species3 -0.4905172 0.4699644  1.0000000
```

Graphical representation:

```
ddfm = melt(ddf, id="Week")
ddfm
   Week variable value
1     1 species1   150
2     2 species1   250
3     3 species1   700
4     4 species1    80
5     5 species1     0
6     1 species2  1000
7     2 species2  1500
8     3 species2  1400
9     4 species2  2000
10    5 species2   500
11    1 species3     0
12    2 species3     0
13    3 species3     0
14    4 species3  1800
15    5 species3   600

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ddfm, aes(x=Week, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]